# Error flushing XmlSerializer buffer when sending soap request (The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.)

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, soap, .net-core

I'm getting an error when attempting to send a request to a ubiquitous peer-to-peer payments platform from .NET Core 3.1. The code is pretty standard for auto-generated SOAP, but here is the auto-generated model that I'm trying to serilaize:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="<redacted>")]
    public partial class EbMtvnSvcReq
    {
        
        private MtvnSvcVerType mtvnSvcVerField;
        
        private string msgUUIDField;
        
        private PrcsParmsType prcsParmsField;
        
        private ServiceRequestType[] svcField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public MtvnSvcVerType MtvnSvcVer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mtvnSvcVerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mtvnSvcVerField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string MsgUUID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.msgUUIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.msgUUIDField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
        public PrcsParmsType PrcsParms
        {
            get
            {
                return this.prcsParmsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.prcsParmsField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Svc", Order=3)]
        public ServiceRequestType[] Svc
        {
            get
            {
                return this.svcField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.svcField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception thrown:

```
System.Exception : The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.    at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode) at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode) in /_/src/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/Inflater.cs:line 300
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadInflateOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32& bytesRead) in /_/src/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/Inflater.cs:line 266
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, Int32& bytesRead) in /_/src/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/Inflater.cs:line 122
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateVerified(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length) in /_/src/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/Inflater.cs:line 92
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.<FinishReadAsyncMemory>d__54.MoveNext() in /_/src/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs:line 506
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 151
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 369
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.<GetStreamAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpResponseMessageHelper.cs:line 316
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 151
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 369
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.<ReadChunkedBufferedMessageAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpResponseMessageHelper.cs:line 190
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 151
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 369
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.<ParseIncomingResponse>d__7.MoveNext() in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpResponseMessageHelper.cs:line 58
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 151
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 369
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<ReceiveReplyAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelFactory.cs:line 1098
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 151
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 369
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsync>d__33.MoveNext() in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/RequestChannel.cs:line 280
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 151
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 369
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.<RequestAsyncInternal>d__32.MoveNext() in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/RequestChannel.cs:line 239
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 180
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 151
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:line 369
   at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task`1 task) in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/Internals/System/Runtime/TaskHelpers.cs:line 282
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/RequestChannel.cs:line 228
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/RequestChannelBinder.cs:line 107
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/ServiceChannel.cs:line 758
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs) in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/ServiceChannel.cs:line 715
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/ServiceChannelProxy.cs:line 372
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args) in /_/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/ServiceChannelProxy.cs:line 144
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 63
   at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args) in /_/src/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy/src/System/Reflection/DispatchProxyGenerator.cs:line 162
   at generatedProxy_1.SendMessage(SendMessageRequest )
   at <my code>
```

I followed the internal code and it seems to fail trying to flush the buffer.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Do you have an error calling the service with auto generated code?I mean you didn't modify the auto generated code.

Comment: It did need modifications. It was generated from a local wsdl file.

Comment: If you modify the auto generated code, it may lead to differences between the client configuration and the server configuration, resulting in the call failure. My suggestion is not to modify the auto generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the buffer values to a lower value (than int.Max) in the GetBindingForEndpoint method:

```
        System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding();
        result.MaxBufferSize = 1024000;
        result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
        result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024000;
        result.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
        ...
        result.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
        result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        return result;
```